# MediaQuery Causing entire app to disappear Flutter

Tags: flutter, debugging

I want to preface that I'm very new and this is my first app.

I'm trying to add a width and a height to my app I was told that this would do the trick but now my entire app is not on screen. Here was my original code. the original code is great but I can't add constraints like a max width or a max height.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

int currentPage = 0;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController ctrl = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: PageView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              controller: ctrl,
              children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                        blurRadius: 500,
                        offset: Offset(10, 10))
                  ]),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                        blurRadius: 500,
                        offset: Offset(10, 10))
                  ]),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                        blurRadius: 500,
                        offset: Offset(10, 10))
                  ]),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.red,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                        blurRadius: 500,
                        offset: Offset(10, 10))
                  ]),
            ),
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is what i changed it to and what caused the app to disappear.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

int currentPage = 0;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { 
  final PageController ctrl = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
  return MaterialApp( 
    home: Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                        blurRadius: 500,
                        offset: Offset(10, 10))
                  ]),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                        blurRadius: 500,
                        offset: Offset(10, 10))
                  ]),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                        blurRadius: 500,
                        offset: Offset(10, 10))
                  ]),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.red,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                        blurRadius: 500,
                        offset: Offset(10, 10))
                  ]),
            ),
          ])
    ), ); } }
```

So basically every time I add this line

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .80,
```

The app disappears and I'm not sure why. Could anybody help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the PageView in a Builder:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

int currentPage = 0;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController ctrl = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Builder(
          builder: (context) => PageView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .80,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.green,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 500,
                          offset: Offset(10, 10))
                    ]),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 500,
                          offset: Offset(10, 10))
                    ]),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 500,
                          offset: Offset(10, 10))
                    ]),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: 30, left: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.red,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey[500],
                          blurRadius: 500,
                          offset: Offset(10, 10))
                    ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This should fix it. The problem is that the context that you are using is not a child of MaterialApp.

Comment: Thank You! I Really Appreciate your help! Im running into the same issue though its not changing the width it's still full screen.